# C++ no command prompt output?

Tags: c++, iostream

```
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    std::cout << 'hi';
    std::cout << "hello";

}
```

When I run this code on windows, I don't see any output. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I think its an issue on my machine, hence my question. I understand it could work in theory, but I want to know why it isn't working in practice. (On my windows computer)

Comment: Why single quote in `'hi'`?

Comment: use `std::cout << "hi";` with double quotation. Double quotation is used for print one or more than one character. single quotation is used for only one character.

Comment: How are you compiling and running it?

Comment: How are you compiling your program, and how are you running it?

Answer (score 0):

some of the compilers will close the output windows after executing the code, so we use `getchar()` or `getch()` or `system("Pause")` at the end of the code. so the output windows will wait for a key press event to close the output window. so you can see your output.

Answer (score -1):

```
std::cout << "hi"; // Double quotes required.
```

[output-here](http://ideone.com/kPi89q)

You should see some output with your original program, though it may not be the desired output. `26729hello`

Comment: I don't see any output

Comment: @JulianGoddard, follow the ideone link I have provided, you should see an output `hihello`

Comment: I think its an issue on my machine, hence my question. I understand it could work in theory, but I want to know why it isn't working in practice. (On my windows computer)

Comment: How do you compile on windows ? Do you have an IDE ?

Answer (score -1):

The buffers of `std::cout` are not being flushed to the console.

Try Running:

```
#include <iostream>


int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    std::cout << "hi";
    std::cout << "hello"<<std:endl;

}
```

The issue is that the `std::cout` is storing the text `"hihello"` in an internal buffer, but this buffer is not being "flushed" which in this case means written to the console window.

Comment: `cout` is automatically flushed when `main` ends. As long as the program terminates normally (i.e., doesn't crash), this shouldn't be an issue.